# read from user strings of different length into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
class JavaStringArray
{
    private String[] toppings = {"Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Black Olives"};

    public JavaStringArray()
    {
        int size = toppings.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(toppings[i]);
        }
    }
}
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JavaStringArray strings = new JavaStringArray();
    }
}
```

I have written a program to store strings of different lengths into an array in different indexes i wanted to achieve this by letting a user type in the strings of any length but he/she goes to a next index if he/she presses enter key for simplicity i only allow three strings to be stored.... how can i achieve that?

Comment: Use double dimensional array will solve problem search google for more

Comment: you can do this by using scanner class of java.util package

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I made some minor edits to improve your post. I encourage you to edit it to improve the writing (changing "i" to "I"). People are more likely to help if they see effort in writing the question. Good luck!

Comment: please can you share sample code is it the normal scanner or something more than it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String[] array = new String[5];

            System.out.println("Please enter 5 names to sort");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = input.nextLine();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }

        }
    }
```

> the important part is nextline that only adds an index if the enter button is pressed